# ggplot2, broom: how to add lines to plot of factor vs. continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, broom

In the plot below, I show values of $R^2$ from a set of models fit to subsets of a data set using `dplyr` and `broom`.  I'd like to connect the points by lines, or else draw horizontal lines to each point, as in a traditional dot plot.  How can I do this?

[image]

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)
library(broom)

# separate models for continents
models <- gapminder %>%
    filter(continent != "Oceania") %>%
    group_by(continent) %>%
    do(mod = lm(lifeExp ~ year + pop + log(gdpPercap), 
                data=.)
      )
models %>% glance(mod)

gg <- 
    models %>%
    glance(mod) %>%
    ggplot(aes(r.squared, reorder(continent, r.squared))) +
        geom_point(size=4) +
        ylab("Continent") 
gg
```

I tried adding `geom_line()`, and can't understand how I use a `group` aesthetic in this context

```
gg + geom_line()
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
the group aesthetic?


gg + geom_line(aes(group=continent))
```

Alternatively, I tried `geom_line()`, as below, without success:

```
> gg + geom_hline(yintercept=levels(continent))
Error in levels(continent) : object 'continent' not found
```

Comment: `gg + geom_line(aes(group = 1))` works fine! Basically, points are connected _within_ groups, and by setting group to 1 all points will be connected. Not sure if the lines are informative, however. Get horizontal lines using `gg + geom_segment(aes(xend = 0, yend = ..y..))`.

Comment: Ah! Beautiful, and more informative than connected lines.  The `yend=..y..` was what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but I would question the use of a connecting line. Generally such lines suggest a logical progression to the sequence of observations, e.g. number of events over time. Is there such an order in these data?

```
gg <- 
  models %>%
  glance(mod) %>%
  mutate(group = 1) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(r.squared, reorder(continent, r.squared), group = group) ) +
  geom_path() + 
  geom_point(size=4) +
  ylab("Continent") 
gg
```

Comment: The ordering is based on R^2 values, achieved by using `reorder(continent, r.squared)`.  I hadn't considered `geom_path()` here, but this connects the points in alphabetic order, not what I want. Ah!! `geom_line()` does what I want here.